Service worker for 3 pages in angular, waiting state not reached unless there's a debugger in developer tools
tldr: If the service worker needs to update, if I know it has the "waiting" state, I want to tell the user to close the tab and start agin
I have an angular SPA with 3 pages. I use router.navigateByUrl to navigate between them
I have a service worker which I use to cache all the js/css and some html on the pages. It all appears to work.
The angular pages call a web server with json calls
If the service worker changes at a later date I want to output a popup telling the user to close his tabs and start again, something which seems like it should be pretty easy to do
I've seen the udacity course and the service worker lifecycle guide but I don't understand why I can't get this working
What I've found is I have this code
   function common()
   {
       var reg = this;

       console.log("awaitStateChange");

       console.log("awaitStateChange, this.state: " + this.state)

       if (reg.waiting)
       {
           alert("waiting")
           console.log("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------awaitStateChange, reg.waiting");

           reg.waiting.addEventListener('awaitStateChange, statechange', common)
           reg.waiting.addEventListener('updatefound, updatefound', common)
       }

       if (reg.active)
       {
           console.log("awaitStateChange, reg.active");

           reg.active.addEventListener('awaitStateChange, statechange', common)
           reg.active.addEventListener('updatefound, updatefound', common)
       }

       if (reg.installing)
       {
           console.log("awaitStateChange, reg.installing");

           reg.installing.addEventListener('awaitStateChange, statechange', common)
           reg.installing.addEventListener('updatefound, updatefound', common)
       }
   }

   registration.addEventListener('awaitStateChange', common);
   registration.addEventListener('updatefound', common);

(this is me attempting to wire into everything just to get something working)
If I place a debugger keyword in awaitStateChange then when it's hit in the developer tools the "reg.waiting" variable has a value, if I don't then it doesn't?
Specifically

The first time the page loads I see "reg.installing"
The second time I don't see anything
If I change the service worker then I see "reg.active", "reg.installing"

Why don't I see reg.waiting without the debugger keyword?
I also have this code which never fires
   window.addEventListener('load', function (e)
   {
       navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function (registration)
       {
           alert('ready')
       });
   });

